# Are closed convex subsets of a Banach space weakly closed without the axiom of choice?

Tags: reference-request, convexity, axiom-of-choice, hahn-banach-theorem

It is a well-known fact that closed convex sets in Banach spaces are weakly closed. The common proof is based on the Hahn-Banach theorem that uses the axiom of choice. Is there any proof of this fact that avoids the axiom of choice and uses only ZF?

Comment: Asaf's answer is simple and to the point, but I can't help myself from giving another example. In Solovay's model (with all subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ Lebesgue measurable), the dual space of $\ell^\infty$ is $\ell^1$, so the weak topology on $\ell^\infty$ is the same as the weak-* topology (as the dual of $\ell^1$). Therefore the unit ball of $c_0$ is norm-closed in $\ell^\infty$, but not weakly closed, because it is not weak-* closed (proving these facts does not require choice).

Comment: @Robert: Since you mentioned Solovay's model, $\ell^\infty/c_0$ has a trivial dual there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course not.

The Hahn–Banach is equivalent to the assertion that $X^*$ is nontrivial for any nontrivial Banach space (or normed space, if you prefer).

This means that if HB fails, there is a nontrivial Banach space $X$ whose weak topology is indiscrete, and in particular no set (other than $X$ and $\varnothing$) is weakly closed.